# how to conditionally add mydatepicker disablescince prop only for a particular field in angular

Tags: angular, ngx-mydatepicker

present mydatepicker options are as below:
in ts file

```js
myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    // other options...
    dateFormat: 'dd-mmm-yyyy',
    editableDateField: false,
    openSelectorOnInputClick: true,
};
```

html file:

```html
<my-date-picker
    #subjectdob="ngModel"
    editableDateField="false"
    maxlength="10"
    name="subjectdob"
    [(ngModel)]="serviceRequestFormDetails.srfSubjectDetails.dateOfBirth"
    [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
    required
></my-date-picker>
```

where as in html file i am having multiple date pickers and for only dateofibirth field i want to use disableSince prop got struck here.can any one help me to achieve this?

Comment: There are a couple of libraries named my-date-picket, which npm package are you using?

Comment: using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mydatepicker sorry i forgot to mention  it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another IMyDpOptions object and extend the common properties using spread operator and add the extra `disableSince` property to the variable

```js
  myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    // other options...
    dateFormat: "dd-mmm-yyyy",
    editableDateField: false,
    openSelectorOnInputClick: true
  };

  myDOBDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    ...this.myDatePickerOptions,
    disableSince: { year: 2020, month: 10, day: 27 }
  };
```

use `myDOBDatePickerOptions` for only the `dateofibirth` field

```html
<my-date-picker
  #subjectdob="ngModel"
  editableDateField="false"
  maxlength="10"
  name="subjectdob"
  [(ngModel)]="serviceRequestFormDetails.srfSubjectDetails.dateOfBirth
  [options]="myDOBDatePickerOptions"
  required
></my-date-picker>
```

Comment: thak you very much its working, but is there any other way rather than using options multiple times????

Comment: @Monika, Was not able to figure out another solution, Consider Upvoting / Accepting answer if my solution was helpful.